# Can't terminate command from a different process

Tags: bash, process, timeout, pipe, exit

I have a command "command1" that runs indefinitely (must be killed with Ctrl+c), and that at random intervals outputs new lines to stdout. My goal is to run it and see if it outputs a certain "target" line within 10 seconds. If the target output is generated, stop immediately with success, otherwise wait for the 10 seconds and fail.

I came up with this:

```
timeout 10 bash -c '(while read line; do [[ "$line" == "target" ]] && break; done < <(command1))'
```

It works, but the problem is that when a match is found, although the timeout command completes and returns successfully, command1 will continue to run indefinitely as a background process. I need it to stop as well when "break" is executed. If a match is not found, and the timeout expires, command1 is stopped correctly.

I also tried this:

```
timeout 10 bash -c '(command1 | while read line; do [[ "$line" == "target" ]] && exit; done)'
```

Which does not leave any spurious processes running. The problem is that the exit command does not terminate command1 since it is in a separate process, and the timeout always expires even if the target is found before.

I was exploring some alternative options, such as wait -n, but the same problem persists, and I must use bash 4.2, so wait -n isn't even an option.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know if `command1` catches and handles SIGTERM? Have you tried other signals?

Comment: @oguzismail Yes, it responds gracefully to SIGINT and SIGTERM and stops itself correctly when it receives either one.

Answer (score 0):

When `command1` does not terminate itself, you can kill it manually.
By the way: Instead of `while read ...` you can use `grep`.

```
timeout 10 bash -c 'command1 | (grep -m1 -Fx "target"; pkill -P $PPID command1)'
```

`-P $PPID` ensures that only the `command1` from this command is killed, and not some other `command1` that might run in another shell at the same time.

This assumes that `command1` is a single command, and not something like `(cmd1; cmd2; ...)`. For that case, you could simply kill the whole bash process using `kill $PPID`.

Comment: Thanks, piping to grep instead of to while read works, and doing kill $PPID also works. However, pkill -P $PPID command1 does not. command1 is indeed a single command but I cannot seem to kill just it without causing a massacre. kill $PPID, although it gets the job done, is a bit barbaric because it kills the timeout command, rather than just command1, which would allow timeout to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Found what works best for my case:

```
timeout 10 bash -c 'grep -q -m1 "target" <(command1); pkill -P $!'
```

All processes terminate gracefully when either the target is found or the timeout expires. If found, command returns 0, if not found, command returns 124.
Thank you @Socowi for some very helpful hints that put me on the right track.